# Access On Lost Focus Event in POP Up Windows

Tags: ms-access, popup

my Question is if there is a way to use the OnLostFocus Event to fire on pop up windows in Access. I have a main windows which is a PopUp window and it hides Access into the Task Bar and if you are not an Admin you should not maximize Access. I tried it with a timer but this does not work well, because it slows everything down and does not look good with the consitent windows hourglass.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to catch the event handler, you can insert

`DoCmd.OpenForm "YourFormName"`

Right click in the top left square just below your form name, where the rulers meet. Select `Properties` -> `Event` -> `On Lost Focus` -> Click on the `...` -> `Code Builder`.

Another route, if you have a main window which is the anchor of your project that allows navigation to all other forms, you can just keep it minimized and restore it when you need to. The `OnLostFocus` event, to me, seems a little silly in this scenario but if it's what you want to do this should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the On Lost Focus event does not fire if the form is a Pop Up form and I do not want normal users to see the Access Main Form to mess around with the Tabels, Reports, Forms or Querys. So I try to work around that.